# Sine and cosine functions

Tags: trigonometry

I am a bit stuck on the following question:

"Simplify the following expression:

$\sin x + \sin (x+\frac{\pi}{2}) + \sin(x+\frac{3\pi}{2})+ \sin (x+2\pi) $"

What I did was draw out the unit circle, and I see that

$\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos x$
and $ \sin(x+\frac{3\pi}{2})=-\cos x$

So they cancel out.

but then $\sin x=\sin (x+2\pi)$.

Therefore, the answer should be $2 \sin x$

But the answer accompanying the question says it should be $sinx$ instead. Where did I go wrong?

P.S. I am really bad at writing names for question titles and tags. Please don't report me for it. Sorry in advance

Comment: You are correct it is $2 \sin x$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$ so $sin(x+2π)=\sin(x)\cos(2π)+\cos(x)\sin(2π)=\sin(x)$ as $\cos(2π)=\cos(0)=1,\sin(2π)=\sin(0)=0$ hope its clear now. So its $\sin(x)+\sin(x)=2\sin(x)$ i think its a typo.

Comment: I think OP knows the obvious fact that $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x).$ Also it needs editing!

Comment: What sort of editing

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now. I guess somehow I saw a previous instant in time where the math render hadn't been done yet. Not saying your fault...